# Raspberry Pi EGL - How to use fb1?

Tags: opengl-es, raspberry-pi, egl

I am trying to modify the hello_triangle example (`/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_triangle`) on my Raspberry Pi to output to fb1 instead of fb0.

I have searched everything I can think of with no answers (it could be I don't know what to search for).

It seems like the line I need to modify is this line:

```
state->display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
```

The docs state the parameter is of type `NativeDisplayType` and "Specifies the display to connect to. EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY indicates the default display." However, it does not give any information on how to list/find available displays.

`EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY` is defined as `(NativeDisplayType)0` so I guessed that 0 referred to fb0, but using `(NativeDisplayType)1` for fb1 caused `eglGetDisplay` to return `EGL_NO_DISPLAY`.

The original example outputs to fb0 as it should, no problems there.
I also know my display is working correctly as I can use `fbi` to display images on fb1 just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Answer: You can't.

For details see my [post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=58952&sid=e1e438779d3233ba8a9f56940201b194) on the Raspberry Pi forums.

> EGL on the RPi doesn't use the linux framebuffers at all, not fb1 nor fb0. The graphics hardware works at a higher level (dispmanx), the display is made up of multiple layers, when linux starts it creates one layer to cover the full screen for fb0. When you create a window with EGL you also create a new layer and tell the hardware to show it in front of the others.